# Two different Raycast 2D are hitting at the same time when i touch one of them in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick, 2d, raycasting

I create one raycast 2D to destroy the first gameObject on click and created a second raycast 2D to destroy the second gameObject on click.

When i click on the first gameObject both gameObjects are destroyed at the same time, why does that happen and How can I make it destroy only the object I touched?

```
// First gameObject Script
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

RaycastHit2D hit1Up = Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, 0.5f, Vector2.up * 0.35f);
RaycastHit2D hit1Bottom = Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, 0.5f, Vector2.down * 0.77f);
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.up * 0.35f, Color.green);
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * 0.77f, Color.green);

Ray firstRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
     {

         if (hit1Up.collider != null || hit1Bottom.collider != null)
         {
             if (hit1Up.collider.tag == "TagName1" || hit1Bottom.collider.tag == "TagName1")
             {
                 Debug.Log("You touched TagName1");
                 destroy(this.gameObject);
             }
         }

     }


// Second gameObject Script
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

RaycastHit2D hit2Up = Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, 0.5f, Vector2.up * 0.35f);
RaycastHit2D hit2Bottom = Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, 0.5f, Vector2.down * 0.77f);
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.up * 0.35f, Color.yellow);
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * 0.77f, Color.yellow);

Ray secondRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
     {

         if (hit2Up.collider != null || hit2Bottom.collider != null)
         {
             if (hit2Up.collider.tag == "TagName2" || hit2Bottom.collider.tag == "TagName2")
             {
                 Debug.Log("You touched TagName2");
                 destroy(this.gameObject);
             }
         }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## if (mouse is down) { check that the object I'm interested in exists, then destroy it }

Your code isn't checking that the ray *actually hit the object!* Or, for that matter, even performing a ray cast to see if the ready his *anything at all.*

```
if (hit2Up.collider != null || hit2Bottom.collider != null)
```

Gosh, I should hope this is true before your code ever runs. This check is useless.

```
if (hit2Up.collider.tag == "TagName2" || hit2Bottom.collider.tag == "TagName2")
```

I presume this will either always be true, or always false. Given that your code is destroying the object, I suspect that it is true. This check is useless.

What you should do:

1. Call `Physics.raycast` using the `out RaycastHit` parameter (this will be wrapped in an if statement, if you don't hit anything, no need to perform any additional checks)
2. Check that the `hit.collider == hitUp.collider`

You also don't need two scripts for this, the same one used twice with different values will suffice.

Example implementation:

```
string tagName;

Update() {
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
        if(hit.collider.CompareTag(tagName)) {
            Debug.Log("You touched " + tagName);
            destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: if you are using the 2D physics, you need to use `RaycastHit2D` and `Physics2D` respectively. The 2D and 3D physics engines don't in any way communicate.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!=), I will try this out. To be clear 1. if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitUp)) 2. of course, if(hit.collider == hitUp.collider)

Comment: Almost. There are a bunch of versions of the `raycast` method, depending on your exact needs. But it will be a variant similar to `RaycastHit hit; if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) { if (hit.collider == hitUp.collider) { ... } }` (where hit is a local variable, hitUp is your class level field (NOT a RaycastHit type!) that references the object; you can also compare tags, in which case you'd need a string at the class level). Note: if you are using the 2D physics, you need `RaycastHit2D` and `Physics2D`

Comment: I get an error when I use: 'RaycastHit2D top = Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, 0.5f, Vector2.up * 0.35f); Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); if(Physics2D.Raycast(ray, out top))
            {

            }'

Comment: I'll update my answer with more usable code when I get home on a real keyboard, but: (1) you didn't say what the error was and (2) you have two casts and are trying to use the return of one as the `out` parameter of the other.

Comment: oh sorry, the error is on ray and top. There's no error on the rest. I wanted to add ray and bottom but i was stuck on ray and top becoming errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Draco18s for your response, it helped me come up with the 2D version logic I needed via some research. Cheers!

```
string tagName1, tagName2;

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Vector2.zero);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            //Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag(tagName1))
            {
                print(tagName1);
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            } else if (hit.collider.CompareTag(tagName2))
            {
                print(tagName2);
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```